# Can C programs have Python GUI?

Tags: python, c, wxpython, pyqt

My friend has an application written in `C` that comes with a GUI made using `GTK` under Linux. Now we want to rewrite the GUI in python (`wxpython` or `PyQT`).

I don't have experience with Python and don't know how to make Python communicate with C. I'd like to know if this is possible and if yes, how should I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its possible to call 'C' functions from Python.

Please look into SWIG(deprecated) also Python provides its own Extensibility API. You might want to look into that.

Also google CTypes.

LINKS:

[Python Extension](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)

A simple example:
I used Cygwin on Windows for this. My python version on this machine is 2.6.8 - tested it with test.py loading the module called "myext.dll" - it works fine. You might want to modify the `Makefile` to make it work on your machine.

### original.h

```
#ifndef _ORIGINAL_H_
#define _ORIGINAL_H_

int _original_print(const char *data);

#endif /*_ORIGINAL_H_*/
```

### original.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "original.h"

int _original_print(const char *data)
{
  return printf("o: %s",data);
}
```

### stub.c

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "original.h"

static PyObject *myext_print(PyObject *, PyObject *);

static PyMethodDef Methods[] = {
  {"printx", myext_print, METH_VARARGS,"Print"},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initmyext(void)
{
  PyObject *m;
  m = Py_InitModule("myext",Methods);
}

static PyObject *myext_print(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
  const char *data;
  int no_chars_printed;
  if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &data)){
      return NULL;
  }
    no_chars_printed = _original_print(data);
    return Py_BuildValue("i",no_chars_printed);  
}
```

### Makefile

```
PYTHON_INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/python2.6
PYTHON_LIB = -lpython2.6
USER_LIBRARY = -L/usr/lib
GCC = gcc -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DMAJOR_VERSION=1 -DMINOR_VERSION=0 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 

win32 : myext.o
    - gcc -shared myext.o $(USER_LIBRARY) $(PYTHON_LIB) -o myext.dll

linux : myext.o
    - gcc -shared myext.o $(USER_LIBRARY) $(PYTHON_LIB) -o myext.so

myext.o: stub.o original.o
    - ld -r stub.o original.o -o myext.o

stub.o: stub.c
    - $(GCC) -c stub.c -o stub.o

original.o: original.c
    - $(GCC) -c original.c -o original.o

clean: myext.o
    - rm stub.o original.o stub.c~ original.c~ Makefile~
```

### test.py

```
import myext
myext.printx('hello world')
```

### OUTPUT

> o: hello world

Comment: hi, yeah i found out about swig while searching but I thought it wont be possible to use because my GTK+ codes are written in c files only so, it might create issues!!

Comment: hello @Aniket- i tried a simple CODE given on SWIG site itself!! and out of my amusement the code is NOT working!! i tried exactly the same procedure with exactly the same code then too..!! how cum is it possible!!

Comment: @rathin2j swig is deprecated, no support available from the community. Why don't you try standard extension by Python? Also what version of python are you using? I have heard its incompatibility with Python 3.x

Comment: i thought swig might be easy thats why and i looked in to standard extension, but didnt quite understood how to implement,

and i am using python 2.7.3 on ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @rathin2j what part of it did you not get? was the simplest example I could give

Comment: @aniket- no..no.. it's not ur fault,it's at my side, i am not having programming background thats why,

and the part which i didnt understood was "do i have to modify my c CODE to be able to make it compatible with this EXTENSION??" means i have to change c file SYNTAX right..??

Comment: @rathin2j well technically you don't need to modify the C source code, you just have to link another file with the application. This file will contain stub functions that are called by the Python Interpreter. Once called, these stub functions can call the _actual_ C functions that do the necessary work. Are you seeing where I am getting to? I don't need to modify my existing work at all

Comment: @rathin2j let me make a little executable code for you and show you how to extend python's functionality with C code.

Comment: @aniket-OH!! that will be great.. thank u very much... it is very kind of u!!

Comment: @rathin2j see that's a simple example where I am never going to modify `_original_print`, instead I will play around with the `myext_print` in the `stub.c` file.

Comment: @rathin2j: If creating the Python bindings requires a lot of tedious stubbing, consider using [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro), which is used by PyQt and also the next gen of wxPython named "Phoenix". [Cython](http://www.cython.org) might be a better fit for a smaller project.

Comment: @Aniket- oh thank u very much for putting this much efforts!! now it's crystal clear..!! so i need not to touch my c.. i just have to write a "STUB" file.. and for that the "python extension" is used!!

woow..really thanks again..!!

Comment: @eryksun- okk perhaps i'll look in to that also.. NOW there are TOO MANY options!! :) so will have to think over them.. and NO project is not small(well it depends' if u call it big or small :), comprising 30000+ lines of CODEs!!

Comment: @Aniket-hello there, actually i totally missed a important aspect of  work which i am carrying forward,(until one of my respected sir told me)
it is..
i was having this issue while working on this open source project 
http://ipdc.codeplex.com/ so,in this project i want to port it's current[GTK+2.4] GUI to Python, if possible can u give me a Project specific guidance!?? or if u can work together with us then it would be great!! :)

Comment: @rathin2j :-) I will see what I can do

Comment: @Aniket-okk.. at ur convenience.. no hurry :)

Comment: ctypes is OK, but you might be better off using Cython or CFFI.

Answer (score 2):

> Sorry but i don't have python experience so don't know how to make Python communicate with C program.

Yes, that's exactly how you do it.  Turn your C code into a Python module, and then you can write the entire GUI in Python.  See [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/).

Comment: Okk!!but will it affect my program performance?? and then wont my WHOLE program converted in to python??

Comment: @rathin2j: Don't worry about performance.  And no, you only write your GUI in Python, the rest of your code is still in C.  When you turn your C code into a Python module, it is still written in C.

Comment: oh i c!! sorry for the silly question but, where would i write my GUI CODE?? in separate file, and over there i have to import those converted modules right???! :)

Comment: Okk!! i got the IDEA.. but dont know howmuch i'l be able to do it.. so will try and let u know.. THANK U so much!! (^_^)

N.B: can i use SWIG?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option between C or C#(Sharp) then go with C# and use visual studio, you can build the GUI by dragging and dropping components easy. If you want to do something in python look up **wxPython**. Java has a built in GUI builder known as swing. You'll need some tutorials, but unless this program doesn't need to be portable just go with C# and build it in 10 minutes .

Also, you can write your code in C and export it as a python module which you can load from python. It`s not very complicated to set up some C functions and have a python GUI which calls them. To achieve this you can use **SWIG, Pyrex, BOOST**.